# Adding floating action button with drawable layout is not visible in Android

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app. In my app, I am using drawer layout as main layout. There is a Frame Layout inside drawer layout for main content. main content is replaced with Fragment when an item form drawer is clicked. Fragment can contain listview, scroll,gridview or whatever.

What I want is a floating action button fixed at the right bottom of the screen. That must be in the main layout(DrawerLayout) because it will contain for all fragment replaced. I added a floating action button to main layout. But I cannot see it when I run my app.

This is the main layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- This LinearLayout represents the contents of the screen  -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- The ActionBar displayed at the top -->
        <include
            layout="@layout/action_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:background="@color/whitesmoke"
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:id="@+id/fb_office_btn"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer that comes from the left -->
    <!-- Note that `android:layout_gravity` needs to be set to 'start' -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawer_item"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/drawer_item"
        android:id="@+id/left_nv_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is the screenshot:

[image]

As you can see above, there is not floating action button. How can I fix it?

### Edit

When I change LinearLayout to RelativeLayout, the gridview of main content are showing like below. Action bar is gone away.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
...
>
...
          <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            <!-- The ActionBar displayed at the top -->
            <include
                android:id="@+id/actionBar" // Add this
                layout="@layout/action_bar" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
            <FrameLayout
                android:background="@color/whitesmoke"
                android:id="@+id/main_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/actionBar" // Add this
             />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" // Add this
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" // Add this
                android:id="@+id/fb_office_btn"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>
...
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**OR** you can follow the Android Studio design

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main" // include app_bar_main
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ui.activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/feedback_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fab_feedback"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Change the id of some component like your app.
Hope this help

Comment: So how is my drawer layout ? I need navigation drawer as well. pls

Comment: @WaiYanHein just only change your `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout`

Comment: @WaiYanHein please see my `RelativeLayout` again. you forgot some part in my `RelativeLayout` code

Comment: It works fine for float button. But action bar is gone away. I just edited my question. Please how can I fix it ?

Comment: I have some comment *// Add this* in my RelativeLayout. Did you put it into your layout ?

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked perfectly. I m gonna upvote the answer.